# How to create Pie chart using Plottable.js

Tags: javascript, charts, plottable

I tried to create a pie chart using Plottable.js.
Does anyone know how? I get confused on how to pass the value and put a label in.

Here is my sample data:

```
var store = [{ Name:"Item 1", Total:18 },
             { Name:"Item 2", Total:7 },
             { Name:"Item 3", Total:3},
             { Name:"Item 4", Total:12}];
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the value of each slice with `Pie.sectorValue` and you can turn on the label with `Pie.labelsEnabled` which shows the corresponding value for each sector.
You can also format the labels with `Pie.labelFormatter`

However, I don't think there is a way to show data other than the sector value as the label, but depending on what you want, a legend might work

Here's an example of Pie chart with Legend:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var store = [{ Name:"Item 1", Total:18 },
               { Name:"Item 2", Total:7 },
               { Name:"Item 3", Total:3},
               { Name:"Item 4", Total:12}];
  

  var colorScale = new Plottable.Scales.Color();
  var legend = new Plottable.Components.Legend(colorScale);

  var pie = new Plottable.Plots.Pie()
  .attr("fill", function(d){ return d.Name; }, colorScale)
  .addDataset(new Plottable.Dataset(store))
  .sectorValue(function(d){ return d.Total; } )
  .labelsEnabled(true)
  .labelFormatter(function(n){ return "$ " + n ;});
    
  new Plottable.Components.Table([[pie, legend]]).renderTo("#chart");
    
     
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/palantir/plottable/develop/plottable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/palantir/plottable/develop/plottable.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <svg id="chart" width="350" height="350"></svg>
</div>
```

Or, if all the values are unique, then you can probably hack it with `labelFormatter`

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var store = [{ Name:"Item 1", Total:18 },
               { Name:"Item 2", Total:7 },
               { Name:"Item 3", Total:3},
               { Name:"Item 4", Total:12}];
  var reverseMap = {};
  store.forEach(function(s) { reverseMap[s.Total] = s.Name;});
    
  var ds = new Plottable.Dataset(store);  
  

  var pie = new Plottable.Plots.Pie()
  .addDataset(ds)
  .sectorValue(function(d){ return d.Total; } )
  .labelsEnabled(true)
  .labelFormatter(function(n){ return reverseMap[n] ;})
  .renderTo("#chart");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/palantir/plottable/develop/plottable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/palantir/plottable/develop/plottable.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <svg id="chart" width="350" height="350"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Zoe, btw, how did you find out about Pie? Is there any documentations or sample about Plottable.js? The API (http://plottablejs.org/docs/modules/plottable.html) isn't very useful as there is no explanation nor example.

Comment: there's a couple examples on the components page: http://plottablejs.org/components/plots/pie/

Comment: LOL... I don't know why I missed that! I guess, I went straight to example page :( Thanks Zoe!